# How to take off a one piece uniform?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-uniforms

How do the people on the Enterprise (in Star Trek the Next Generation) take off the uniform in order to use the toilet? The uniform is a one-piece!

Comment: Call Riker. He's an expert.

Comment: [How to Pee in a Onesie Without Wanting to Kill Yourself](https://www.aliceinonesieland.com/faqs/how-to-pee-in-a-onesie-without-wanting-to-kill-yourself)

Comment: @Jeeped - The Season 1 and 2 uniforms were a [form-fitting one-piece jumpsuit](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Starfleet_uniform_(2350s-2370s)?file=Command_uniform%2C_2365.jpg) that you were zipped into

Comment: Selective transporter usage!

Comment: That's actually two questions in one.
(1) How do the actors remove the uniform to go to the toilet? Which Valorum has answered. For more detail, ask the actors!
(2) How do the Enterprise characters remove the uniform for the same purpose? Well now, this leaves room for discussion if there has ever been mention in canon of advanced fabrics that open and close without our familiar zippers, buttons, Velcro, or other fasteners.

Comment: ["This Is Why You Can't Use The Bathroom In A Romper"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qT2UqGaHzH8) - Warning, slightly NSFW

Comment: For the actors, the original TNG jumpsuits appear to have seams down the front which could reasonably be zippers. They have similar-looking seams down the outside of the arms, so there may be zippers there also. I'd imagine the actors would have to pretty much remove the entire uniform for bathroom breaks. As for the 24th century, I'm sure the uniforms are fitted with strategically located and camouflaged fasteners for maximum convenience during rest breaks.

Comment: I expect they prank new cadets by telling them that they can go straight into their suit, then waiting until they find out that you can't

Comment: It's something of a trope that there are no toilets in Star Trek. Perhaps medical science had moved beyond the traditional means of bodily waste disposal?

Comment: @GeoffAtkins You'd be hard pressed to find a toilet in almost any American TV show or movie regardless of the genre.  Unless of course your plot has a bunch of toilet humor EG Austin Powers

Comment: The later seasons modified the uniforms to be two piece pants/shirt combos. The actors hated the design of the season 1-2 uniforms and said they were horribly uncomfortable to wear.

Comment: https://youtu.be/2Pi-8uIF9N8

Comment: I've always presumed there was a hidden zipper.

Comment: @ArlettaS - It's not very hidden

Comment: In one episode, probably "Preemptive Strike", Ro is on a desert planet with Bajoran refugees and has on her regular zipperless top, only to clearly have it swapped between takes so she can unzip it and give it a child, as I recall.    .... So, I guess they have magic invisible zippers in the 24th century...

Comment: Transporters transport all bodily waste away, just don’t ask where to and hope there is never a transporter malfunction that takes you there.

Answer (score 9):

Starfleet one-piece jumpsuits seem to come in two flavours; Front zipping for main character men and rear zipping for main character females.

[image]

[image]

That being the case, the obvious way to go to the toilet would be to zip it down to the waist (or lower back), lower the jumpsuit past your waist to your ankles, void your bowels/bladder, use the three seashells and then do everything back up in reverse.

Comment: loved the three seashells reference!

Comment: @MatíasCánepa - In Kirk's day they used toilet paper; "*“Well, if it isn’t the Enterprise.” Julius Merrill’s unmistakable voice, familiar from dozens of recorded speeches, filtered through the chair speaker. “Nice to hear from you. We were damn near running out of toilet paper out here.”*" - Pocket Books - TOS: Constellations

Comment: Actually, the "first gen" uniforms were front zipping for both men and women and the "second gen" was back zipping for both.

Comment: @BrianOrtiz - If you look at the stills from Encounter at Farpoint, you can see that they tended to go by frontsies for the men and backsies for the women; https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/memoryalpha/images/9/9f/Starfleet_uniforms%2C_2364.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20120205185530&path-prefix=en. That being said, the defining feature regarding zipper choice seems to be whether they needed to make the breasts (for women) or chests (for men) more prominent so it's not always as simple as front/men, back/women.

Comment: @Valorum That still is misleading. If you watch the episode, Troi is the only one without a front zip.

Comment: @BrianOrtiz - And if you look at the battle bridge sequence, you can see that it's pretty interchangeable. Conn Officer Ensign Nobody and Battle Bridge Conn Officer Colm Meaney are both wearing rear-zippers; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SHz2GIPpeXo

Comment: @Valorum Watch in HD. They have front zippers. https://i.gyazo.com/26173af1ae3ee01042349a73ec25aa61.jpg https://i.gyazo.com/5976bbe66208a46ba5a3dc3ffcf31fe3.jpg