# Where do replicators get their material?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, replicator

My fiance just asked me if replicators got their matter by dereplicating human waste, and I realized I wasn't sure. Even after researching the matter, I can't find any concrete information. So where does the matter come from? Is it from recycled human waste, or is there some sort of energy-matter conversion involved?

Comment: I'd have to look it up, but the short answer, as I recall, is both. Waste products are converted into energy, and at least some of that energy is used by the replicators to create new matter.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Assuming you're referring to TNG (onwards), Federation starships carry a feedstock of raw materials that can be easily converted into the widest possible range of substances by the replicator systems. Before this, starships (like the Enterprise NX-1 and Enerprise NCC-1701) used reclamation systems to process waste *water* back into potable water. There's no indication that **any** of the ships we see processed solid human waste back into food.

Per the [TNG Technical Manual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_The_Next_Generation_Technical_Manual)

> In order to minimize replicator power requirements, **raw stock for food
>   replicators is stored in the form of a sterilized organic particulate
>   suspension** that has been formulated to statistically require the least
>   quantum manipulation to replicate most finished foodstuffs

and

> **Material that cannot be directly recycled by mechanical or chemical
>   means is stored for matter synthesis recycling.** This is accomplished
>   by molecular matrix replicators that actually dematerialize the waste
>   materials and rematerialize them in the form of desired objects or
>   materials stored in computer memory. While this process provides an
>   enormous variety of useful items, it is very energy intensive and many
>   everyday consumables (such as water and clothing) are recycled by less
>   energy intensive mechanical or chemical means. **Certain types of
>   consumables (such as foodstuffs) are routinely recycled using matter
>   replication because this results in a considerable savings of stored
>   raw material**

You can tell your fiance that human waste materials are generally [stored and offloaded](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/1243/20774) at Starbase (e.g. rather than being recycled) although such a thing *is possible* and almost certainly happens on long voyages where regular stops aren't feasible (e.g. Voyager).

---

For avoidance of doubt
**Archer** =  Definitely drinking his own recycled urine
**Kirk** = Almost certainly drinking his own recycled urine
**Picard** = Definitely **not** drinking his own urine
**Sisko** = Almost certainly drinking his own recycled urine
**Janeway** = Almost certainly drinking her own recycled urine

Comment: Maybe drinking Sisko's recycled urine is why Worf is more badass in DS9? It's probably more Klingon way...

Comment: I agree with the very detailed answer above, but we can now update it to cover the years that Discovery is set in: https://youtu.be/Tn49wvoXr3g

Comment: @Folk - He might be lying to make a point though

Answer (score -1):

Food and item replicators in the various Star Trek series use waste materials  (garbage and human waste) to create food and items

Comment: Hi there! Do you have a source for that, that you could [edit] in? (note that an earlier answer provided some evidence towards the "no")

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  You should take the [tour](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour) for a better understanding of how to write good answers.  It is preferred if an answer can cite sources, or link to supporting material, especially if a canonical source can be found.